# Node8/Expresss 4 How to get the value of a specific response header property?

Tags: node.js, express, json-server

I currently can access the response header property 'X-Total-Count' set by json-server, but I don't see how to get the value ...

In chrome-web-tools , is stated as

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
X-Powered-By: Express
X-Total-Count: 14
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Total-Count, Link
Link: <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName%7Casc&_page=1&_limit=5>; rel="first", <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName%7Casc&_page=2&_limit=5>; rel="next", <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName%7Casc&_page=3&_limit=5>; rel="last"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
ETag: W/"4a2-UH/ZrGuCnz4JcDB1ZNEu7sRXZro"
Date: Thu, 07 Dec 2017 07:42:32 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

I can access it in my server.js :

```
apiRouter.render = (req, res) => {
  console.log('RES HEADERS: ', res.getHeaders()) 
  console.log('RES TOTAL: ', res.getHeader('X-Total-Count'))
  console.log('RES LINK: ', res.getHeader('Link')) 
  ....
```

And get the log display:

```
RES HEADERS:  { 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  'x-total-count':
   { [Number: 14]
     __wrapped__: { shoppinglists: [Array], users: [Array] },
     __actions__: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     __chain__: true,
     __index__: 0,
     __values__: undefined },
  'access-control-expose-headers': 'X-Total-Count, Link',
  link: '<http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName%7Casc&_page=1&_limit=5>; rel="first", <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName%7Casc&_page=2&_limit=5>; rel="next", <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName%7Casc&_page=3&_limit=5>; rel="last"' }


RES TOTAL:  { [Number: 14]
  __wrapped__:
   { shoppinglists:
      [ [Object],
        ...
        [Object] ],
     users:
      [ [Object],
        ...
        [Object] ] },
  __actions__:
   [ { func: [Function: get], args: [Object], thisArg: [Object] },
     { func: [Function: orderBy], args: [Object], thisArg: [Object] },
     { func: [Function: size], args: {}, thisArg: [Object] } ],
  __chain__: true,
  __index__: 0,
  __values__: undefined }
```

But how can I get the value ? :  14....

thanks for feedback

In json-server , this response header property is set as following :

```
// Slice result
if (_end || _limit || _page) {
  res.setHeader('X-Total-Count', chain.size())
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers',
    `X-Total-Count${_page ? ', Link' : ''}`
  )
}
```

Comment: That's odd, according to the documentation of response.getHeader, you should get a string: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_getheader_name

Comment: thanks for feedback .. solved ,  it's a function returned so got it

Answer (score 1):

res.getHeader('X-Total-Count') is a FUNCTION...  so need to write :

```
     const total = res.getHeader('X-Total-Count')
     console.log('TOTAL: ', total). // => displaying 14
```